# .ini file not creating

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have begun to start working with .ini files because I realise its many advantages compared to a .txt file. Any way, I googled "delphi inifiles" and I am now following a guide on [Delphi About](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/tinifile.htm). However the very first line I tried gave me trouble even though all the syntax is right.

**Delphi About's Code:**

```
IniFile := TIniFile.Create('myapp.ini') ;
```

**My code:**

```
IniFile := TIniFile.Create('SWEDISH_HOUSE_MAFIA.ini');
```

The only difference is the name of the .ini file itself. Also, yes I have:

- Declared 'IniFiles' in the 'uses' clause
- (Locally) Declared IniFile

I have placed that code under FormCreate, but the problem is this .ini file is not created when the program is run. Anyone know what the problem could be? I've asked a friend about it and he said it was a permission issue.

Extra Details:

- OS - Windows 7 Ultimate 64 Bit (Administrative rights)
- Program is stored in - My Documents
- I use - Delphi 2010

Comment: You should *really* qualify your paths completely. If you want to store the INI file in the same directory as the EXE, which is *only* acceptable if the EXE is located in a per-user directory (such as your Documents folder), you should do `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'SWEDISH_HOUSE_MAFIA.ini'`.

Comment: IniFile := TInifile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'SWEDISH_HOUSE_MAFIA.ini');
It still does not work for some reason I do not know.

Comment: Anyhow, we have to guess about what is wrong, because -- of course -- there is no bug in the Delphi VCL/RTL that would make precisely the file name `SWEDISH_HOUSE_MAFIA.ini` invalid. You have either misdiagnosed the problem (are you sure that everything really works out if you rename the INI in the line shown above?), or, perhaps, you already have a file named `SWEDISH_HOUSE_MAFIA.ini` that is read-only or something...

Comment: @petersmileyface, you are wrong about txt files. You can dump your component/Form to a stream, convert this stream to a text using ObjectBinaryToText and save it as a Txt. Using this system is faster than ini files...because you don't have to save/reload each property...With a few tweak using the 'Stored' keyword you can select what to dump or not...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first issue is that the file is only created when you write something to the ini file. I suspect that at present you aren't calling one of the `WriteXXX` methods.

The other issue is that if you don't qualify your path then `TIniFile` will attempt to locate it in the Windows directory and of course you don't have rights to write there. The underlying API that `TIniFile` is based on is the private profile API which has been long deprecated, performs terribly, and is full of strange wrinkles. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725501%28VS.85%29.aspx) states:

> If the lpFileName parameter does not contain a full path and file name for the file, WritePrivateProfileString searches the Windows directory for the file. If the file does not exist, this function creates the file in the Windows directory.

Clearly you should fully qualify your path.

However, I strongly recommend that you consider using `TMemIniFile` rather than `TIniFile` since `TMemIniFile` avoids all the pitfalls of the private profile API.

If you do switch to `TMemIniFile` then remember to call `UpdateFile` before destroying the ini file since this is what will save the settings to the disk.  Otherwise `TMemIniFile` is a drop-in replacement for `TIniFile`.

Comment: Do you know of any online tutorials relating to the use of the TMemIniFile?

Comment: I also thought about this, but I didn't mention it explicitly, because the OP claims that everything works out entirely differently when he uses a different name of the INI file, which, of course, is rather absurd. That's why I wrote my second comment above, asking if the problem isn't misdiagnosed. I think the OP will find out that no file is created even if he replaces the mafia-inspired name by the slighly more dull 'myapp.ini'.

Comment: @peter You can use it just the same way as you do with `TIniFile`. As far as I am aware it is a drop-in replacement. The problems with `TIniFile` extend to correctness too. I believe there are bugs in the private profile API that lies behind it.

Comment: @Andreas My instinct is that peter is not claiming that everything works differently with a different name. I think peter has taken the About code and changed it.

Comment: @peter Ah, I forgot there is one difference between TIniFile and TMemIniFile. See the update (it's also what is behind LU RD's answer).

Comment: Not because I disagree with your answer David, but you were right; I have to use the WriteXXX command for the file to create.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure the file is actually saved on disk, 
use

```
IniFile.UpdateFile
```

Comment: Not true, you have to write something to the file for it to be created.

Comment: @David, yes that goes without saying. :)

Comment: There's no need to call `UpdateFile`. It gets called when the IniFile is destroyed. If you don't write to the file then `UpdateFile` won't create the file.

Comment: @David, oops been working with TMemInifile only since it was introduced.

Comment: Yes, this would almost certainly be the explanation if peter was using `TMemIniFile`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't save ini to application path. Use `%APPDATA%` path. INI without path is created in Windows folder (Win3..XP). On Vista/7 these files are redirected to `\Users\[user]\some-magic-folder` (unless your program runs as "Installer")
2. Using TMemFile will speedup operations a lot. You need call UpdateFile/Free to update file, but it is much faster

Comment: Are you sure? I would rather imagine that it would end up in the same directory as the EXE, or if not possible, in a virtual store.

Comment: Yes, you can try it. This is feature how Vista/7 are back compatible with old-evil-applications.

In Vista/7 ordinary application cannot write to \Windows, \Program files... Just Installers (with nice UAC dialog). Next level is NTFS rigts. You just can't write there. Of course you can grant yourself (as Administrator) write rights, but none of your customers will have this.

Comment: Yes, I know that if a non-priv app is trying to write to the Program Files dir, the Windows dir, ..., then it will end up writing to a per-user 'virtual store' directory instead, and that is great. What I don't really believe is that `TIniFile.Create('myapp.ini')` will create a file in the Windows folder (or a virtual-store Windows folder) by default. I think it will end up in the same dir as the EXE (or a virutal-store folder).

Comment: But I seem to be wrong, although the INI isn't saved *anywhere* on Windows 7... It simple causes an error if I don't qualify the path...

Comment: TIniFile.Create('some.ini') is created in Windows folder.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The name of the initialization file. If this parameter does not contain a full path to the file, the system searches for the file in the Windows directory.

Comment: @DiGi: OK, perhaps if you are running your app with raised privileges. On my system, I get an error if I don't qualify the path.

Comment: Oh I see, I got exception too. But point is simple: Just don't store any configuration files outside %appdata%. And test application with limited account, in WinXP,... :)

Comment: Item 1 is perfect, even i was about to write about that. Kernel wants full pathname otherwise ini-file will go to %windir%. (disagree about exact directory location, tho, different subject)

Comment: +1 Yes, I see the error of my ways. Item 1 is essentially correct. However, a default Delphi 2010 project is not virtualized and there is no redirection.

Answer (score 1):

```
TForm1.btnWriteClick(Sender: TObject); 

var

    myINI : TINIFile;

begin 

    myINI := TINIFile.Create('Tryfolder\myini.ini');

    myINI.WriteString('Settings', 'Text Box', 'Whatever text');

    myINI.Free;

end;
```

Like answer 3 said, you just need to write a value to the ini :) This worked for me (win 7 ultimate 64 bit).

Comment: Please note that refering to a previous answer by number (`Like answer 3 said...`) is not helpful, because the order of answers being displayed can be changed (due to sorting by votes and answer deletion). It would be better to name the person that provided the answer (preceding their name with an @ so that they can be notified that you've referenced them).